# console application crashing C#

Tags: c#, windows, console

So I'm trying to make a console application that calculates interest rates per year. But somehow its crashing down when i assign the deposit year.

The source code is below:

```
using System;
namespace week0502
{
   class Interest
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         decimal p = 0; // principle
         decimal r = 1; // interest rate
         decimal t = 2; // time/years entered
         decimal i = 3; // interest
         decimal a = 4; // new amount
         // prompt for values
         Console.Write("Enter original deposit amount: ");
         p = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.Write("Enter annual interest rate (10% as 10): ");
         r = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.Write("Enter years to save this deposit amount: ");
         t = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.WriteLine();
         // display headers
         Console.WriteLine("Year Rate Amount  Interest  New Amount");
         // calculate new amount on deposit after t amount of years
         for (int n = 1; n <= t; n++)
         {
               // calculations
               i = p * r;
               a = i + p;
               // display contents
               Console.WriteLine("{0, 4}{1, 4}{2, 10:C}{3, 5}{4, 10:C}", n, r, p, i, a);
            } // end for
      } // end main
   } // end class
} // end name
```

Comment: What's the exception? Did you debug through to see what is going on?

Comment: This example just work fine on my compiler. What are your values that you enter in command prompt?

Comment: *Crashing* is not a technical term. It's a very non-technical term. And it is of no value in trying to resolve the issue. Please learn to think more like a programmer.

Comment: "somehow its crashing down" isn't *nearly* enough information. What's happening?

Comment: what is the error it gives and what happens if instead of using the console you just put strings in for testing?

Comment: @user1878363 Add Console.Readline(); after your for loop to prevent the application from closing right after its done with the output

Comment: You do know that identifiers are not limited to a single character right? Instead of `p` and a comment, you can just name the variable `principle`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean it closes after showing the result thats normal if you forget to add `Console.ReadLine()` (wait for user to press enter before closing the application)

```
using System;
namespace week0502
{
   class Interest
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         decimal p = 0; // principle
         decimal r = 1; // interest rate
         decimal t = 2; // time/years entered
         decimal i = 3; // interest
         decimal a = 4; // new amount
         // prompt for values
         Console.Write("Enter original deposit amount: ");
         p = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.Write("Enter annual interest rate (10% as 10): ");
         r = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.Write("Enter years to save this deposit amount: ");
         t = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.WriteLine();
         // display headers
         Console.WriteLine("Year Rate Amount  Interest  New Amount");
         // calculate new amount on deposit after t amount of years
         for (int n = 1; n <= t; n++)
         {
               // calculations
               i = p * r;
               a = i + p;
               // display contents
               Console.WriteLine("{0, 4}{1, 4}{2, 10:C}{3, 5}{4, 10:C}", n, r, p, i, a);
            } // end for
         Console.ReadLine(); //Add this to prevent application from closing
      } // end main
   } // end class
}
```